# how to inject variable in a query Eager Loads

Tags: laravel

Maybe I'm not doing it correctly but I need to bring all the posts with : survey, survey.surveyOptiosn and survey.surveyOptions.values relationship that match the id of the survey itself.

The query works like this, but notice that the query ($query->where('survey_id', 1)->get(); ) I am injecting the variable 1 by hand.
I need that variable to come from the survey_id itself.
I have tried a thousand ways but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
$posts = Post::with([
            'survey' => function ($query) {
                 $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
            },
            'survey.surveyOptions',
            'survey.surveyOptions.values' => function ($query) {
                 $query->where('survey_id', 1)->get();
            },
            'image',
            'categories'
           ])
           ->withCount('comments')
           ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in survey Model

```
use App\Models\SurveyOption;
use App\Models\Value;

Class Survey extends Model
{
   public function values()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
         Value::class,
         SurveyOption::class,
         'survey_id',
         'suvery_option_id',
         'id',
         'id'
      );

   }
}
```

then your query should look like this

```
$posts = Post::with([
            'survey' => function ($query) {
                 $query->withCount('totalSurveys');
            },
            'survey.surveyOptions',
            'survey.values', // here
            'image',
            'categories'
           ])
           ->withCount('comments')
           ->first();
```